# python code just won't work. the decryption doesn't return back the decrypted phrase

Tags: python, encryption

I tried putting print hello's everywhere and tried to find what wasn't working, and the if filename == x part wouldn't work. there certainly is the text.txt file. the program won't respond. It's like the code doesn't exist
please help

```
import os
def translate(y):
    y = y.replace("quebrqerubfq92983rgh", "A")

x = "text.txt"
a = os.path.realpath(__file__)
a = a.split(":")
a = a[0]
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(a + ":"):
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename == x:
                s = open(x, "r")
                y = s.read()
                y = str(y)
                result = translate(y)
                s = s.close()
```

Comment: What is this actually supposed to *do*?

Comment: it's supposed to get text.txt and decrypt what is in it. there is an encryption code other than this, and it works adequately, but still works. I also want to have the text,txt destroyed, (or just deleted) the moment it decrypts. thanks for looking at this post.

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing, returning, nor writing anything, that's your problem.
Your `translate` function needs a return.
And what do you want to do with `y` after you translated it?

Edit: try this out.

```
import os
def translate(y):
    y = y.replace("quebrqerubfq92983rgh", "A")
    return y

x = "text.txt"
a = os.path.realpath(__file__)
a = a.split(":")
a = a[0]
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(a + ":"):
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename == x:
                s = open(x, "r")
                y = s.read()
                y = str(y)
                result = translate(y)
                s = s.close()

print(result)
```

Comment: thanks, It worked, but the result came out multiple times. could you please make the result come out only once?

Comment: Sure, you just have to take the print() out of the loops. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: also, when I did it again, it said it could not find the file it was looking for, even though it was there

Comment: thanks I could fix that. It works quite well now. Thank you